# Correct way to load this JS into wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to make it so that a div fades out once you have scrolled down the page. Im using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ZyKar/3/) which works, however I cannot get it to work when I load it into a single wordpress page.

I tried adding the following in the text editor:

```html
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
    }

});
</script>
```

The div shows (I haven't included the CSS here), however I cannot get the JS working. sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an exact answer on the best way to do it in WP.

Comment: you're missing jquery library

Comment: Try surrounding your existing script with `jQuery(function($){ ..your logic here.. });`  Afaik, wordpress puts jQuery in no conflict mode by default so the '$' isn't tied to jQuery, so you have to either use 'jQuery' or use a form of an IIFE or doc ready and pass in the $ to use it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery library:

```html
<div class="bottomMenu"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.bottomMenu').fadeOut();
    }

});
</script>
```